# How to filter items after fetching data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

I am trying to filter some data from a rest api that I made.

The data is definitely being filtered if I get it locally exactly like this (have a look at the "products" file in this code sandbox that I made): https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-banzai-p10e9

When I try to fetch the data, it does not update the UI with the filtered products. I am guessing that it has to do with a life cycle hook that I am not using but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

This is how I am fetching the data:

```
 componentDidMount () {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products')
            .then((res) => {
                let products = res.data.data.data;
                this.setState({
                    products,
                    filteredProducts: products,
                    isLoading: false
                })   
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

This is the function I am using for filtering the above data:

```
handleFormSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const selectedSizes = [...this.selectedCheckboxes];

        const shallowCopy = [...this.state.filteredProducts];

        let filteredProducts = shallowCopy.filter(product =>
            selectedSizes.every(size =>
                product.stock.some(s => s.stock > 0 && s.size === size)
            )
        );

        let filteredGender = filteredProducts.filter(product => {
            return product.gender.some((item) => {
                return item[this.selectedGender] === false ? null : product;
            });
        });

        let filteredData = filteredGender.filter(product => {
            return product.brand.includes(this.state.activeBrand);
        });

        let sortedPrice = filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
            return this.state.sortBy === "min"
                ? a.price - b.price
                : b.price - a.price;
        });

        this.setState({
            filteredProducts: sortedPrice
        });
    };
```

The UI is in the code sandbox I provided.

Comment: You need to debug your code. log your response and see if you get the same structure as your local data. Also as a side note having nested data object with the same name  `res.data.data.data` looks weird to me.

Comment: Will do and fix the triple data thing that I have going on. Am I missing something though? Am I supposed to be using a life cycle hook for this?

Comment: Could you use async await function and debug. I think it will help to you.

Comment: All I had to do was install and import "axios" and it started working. The Ui is updating upon clicking of filter button.